# Redis pub/sub serialized data struct C data

Tags: c++, c, redis, hiredis

I'd like to store my serialized data on redis and publish to the channel that i've defined. But it seems that there is a problem on SETting the key value at redis. What do i miss for the solution ?

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "hiredis.h"
#include "async.h"
#include "macosx.h"


#define PACKETSIZE sizeof(cloudRANMessage)
#define COMMANDSIZE 256

typedef struct cloudRANMessage
{
unsigned int      station_id;
unsigned int      location_area;
char              command[COMMANDSIZE];
}cloudRANMessage;


void printMyMessage(cloudRANMessage *message)
{
printf("%d\n", message->location_area);
printf("%d\n", message->station_id);
printf("%s\n", message->command);
}

void serialize(cloudRANMessage *message, char *data)
{
assert(data != NULL);
memcpy(data, message, sizeof *message);
}

void deserialize(char *data)
{
cloudRANMessage *tempMessage = malloc(sizeof(cloudRANMessage));  // To store deserialized message.
memset(tempMessage, 0, sizeof(cloudRANMessage));
memcpy(tempMessage, data, sizeof(cloudRANMessage));
printMyMessage(tempMessage);
}

void getCallback(redisAsyncContext *c, void *r, void *privdata) {
redisReply *reply = r;
if (reply == NULL) return;
printf("%s\n", reply->str);                   // Call deserializaton function for the data retrieval.;
/* Disconnect after receiving the reply to GET */
redisAsyncDisconnect(c);
}

void callbackDeserialize(redisAsyncContext *c, void *r, void *privdata) {
redisReply *reply = r;
if (reply == NULL) return;
printf("%s\n", reply->str);                   // Call deserializaton function for the data retrieval.
char *stringReply = reply->element[0]->str;
deserialize(stringReply);
/* Disconnect after receiving the reply to GET */
redisAsyncDisconnect(c);
}

void connectCallback(const redisAsyncContext *c, int status) {
if (status != REDIS_OK) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", c->errstr);
    return;
}
printf("Connected...\n");
}

void disconnectCallback(const redisAsyncContext *c, int status) {
if (status != REDIS_OK) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", c->errstr);
    return;
}
CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
printf("Disconnected...\n");

}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

cloudRANMessage *newcloudRANMessage = malloc(sizeof(cloudRANMessage));
newcloudRANMessage->location_area = 7214;
newcloudRANMessage->station_id = 45632;
strcpy(newcloudRANMessage->command, "HANDOVER\0");
char data[PACKETSIZE];
serialize(newcloudRANMessage, data);

signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
CFRunLoopRef loop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent();
if( !loop ) {
    printf("Error: Cannot get current run loop\n");
    return 1;
}

redisAsyncContext *c = redisAsyncConnect("127.0.0.1", 6379);
if (c->err) {
    /* Let *c leak for now... */
    printf("Error: %s\n", c->errstr);
    return 1;
}

redisMacOSAttach(c, loop);

redisAsyncSetConnectCallback(c,connectCallback);
redisAsyncSetDisconnectCallback(c,disconnectCallback);
redisAsyncCommand(c,getCallback,NULL,"SUBSCRIBE cloudRAN");

                                       // Serialize Data then send to Redis
//redisAsyncCommand(c, getCallback, (char*) "SET", "SET LTEdata %s", data, strlen(data));     // key for our data in this  case is LTEdata
redisAsyncCommand(c,NULL, NULL, "SET LTEdata %s", data);
//redisAsyncCommand(c, getCallback,(char*) "GET", "GET LTEdata");
redisAsyncCommand(c, callbackDeserialize,NULL, "GET LTEdata");

// Publish the information to the all subscribers.
redisAsyncCommand(c,NULL, NULL, "PUB cloudRAN %b",data,strlen(data));


CFRunLoopRun();
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In this call to redisAsyncCommand:

```
redisAsyncCommand(c,NULL, NULL, "SET LTEdata %s", data);
```

any null bytes appearing in `data` will terminate the hiredis string interpolation. Since you are binary encoding, this is likely to be truncating your string. Try specifying the length to make it binary-safe:

```
redisAsyncCommand(c,NULL, NULL, "SET LTEdata %b", data, sizeof(data));
```